# So I disabled the Application Information service

Tags: windows-10, services

Do to a battery problem when upgrading to Windows 10 I disabled the Appinfo service. The problem I am having now is that I cannot get it re-enabled. I get this message when I try and open regedit, task manager and services to try and fix the problem, "The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it." I also got this when I tried installing malwarebytes to run a scan (I don't think it is a virus because this happened as soon as I did the restart after editing appinfo).

My next step was to edit it through command prompt using this line `REG add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Appinfo" /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f` to which I get, "ERROR: Access is denied".

At this point what I am asking is if anyone knows how to get permission to edit the registry through command prompt or a way to get something working again to edit it the normal way.

Comment: boot from a WinPE DVD, run regedit. load the offline registry and change the start value again. Now unmount the registry and boot your Windows

Comment: What exactly did you do to disable it in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I was reminded by a friend that I could probably just boot into safemode(sift+click the restart button on Win10) and re-enable it from there(by going into services and setting it from "disabled" to "manual"), which worked. Although Hysterics suggestion of using a live version of Linux to edit the windows registry would have worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i can suggest you to do is run regedit with administration permission or enable the Administration account by using the command line by typing

```
net user Administrator /active: yes
```

But this should get the same permission as when you right click and select run as administrator.

If that isn’t working then my alternative is to boot into a live Linux and edit the windows registry from there.
there was a way to do that i believe

downvoter, **SPEAK** dont run and hide

Comment: When running cmd as Admin I get the "The service cannot be started..." error from my question. When I run the command you gave I get "System error 5 has occurred access is denied".
The Linux idea is a good one. Unfortunately I just wiped my live USB 5 minutes ago so I won't be able to try it until tomorrow.

Comment: What? your unable to enable the administrator account? (you did right click and run as admin on cmd first right?)
if you cannot enable the admin account then i suspect that there is something wrong with the permission on the file system itself? but i could be wrong about this...
could you confirm that you did indeed run cmd as admin and used the commands?
ah okay, please dont forget to create backups first because any third-party registry editor COULD damge it, you never know what will happen when you use third party tools from linux

Comment: Can confirm, right clicked cmd, ran as admin. Got error "The service cannot be started..." from original quesiton. The command produced the error from my previous comment.

Comment: using windows 7/8 or 10?
if so, then i really do suspect something is wrong with the overall permission, i dont know what it could cause like that right now sorry...

Comment: Its an upgrade from 7 to 10. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The AppInfo service is the thing in Windows that handles elevation requests, when UAC is turned on. You'll need to somehow turn UAC off or reenable the service or use the built-in Admin account. Maybe from a WINPE-based rescue cd?

Comment: The answer is incomplete.  You suggest they elevate a command prompt which isn't possible with that service already disabled.  So I issued the downvote because the answer is not really all that helpful since it's incomplete.  Look forward to the revenge serial downvotes from everyone that disagrees with my comment

Answer (score 0):

I had the same dilemma. I tried to disable as many services I can for a virtual machine, then ended up not able to run anything.
I fixed it by going to the safe mode using the "shift+restart" trick. ( You cannot do this in a RDP session.) The virtual machine goes to a PE environment. There I can run regedit, load the hive from "c:\windows\system32\config\system", edit the entry of "AppInfo", change the "start" from 4 to 3, then unload the hive. After that everything works again.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late (a few years) but this is still relevant and didn't seem anyone completed feedback on this.

I can confirm that I have had the same experience as the thread starter.

- in my experience there was no advice not to turn this off
- when I turned it off (in Windows 10 22H2 now) I kept getting an error dialogue basically stopping me launching all sorts of applications in System Tools (try it if you like experimenting to see what happens)
- restarting in safe mode worked fine and I edited the Services options back to "manual" from what I had changed it to: "disabled"

It has taught me about modern Windows and restart options (shift-click restart), and so now I am looking at it, and no need to install Linux right now. I hate the idea of using modern Windows when you don't have all bases covered, as it becomes a time drain, like when I tried to install Virtual Machines which I basically had to figure out myself to get any function out of it (actually running software, with drivers and such) and it wasn't even HyperV - but the apps have become harder to use and I couldn't find the old ones that were around 10+ years ago that did it all for you no fuss.